# Javascript code to find a text on page and jump to it

Tags: javascript, search, text

there exist similar questions but not quite. This must be easy as well.

Say I've got a large page full of Lorem Ipsum stuff, no div's or p's or any other <>'s - don't want them coz the text is to be wieved with a plain-text editor also, so I want just plain text with br's at most. Nevertheless, to separate sections I use a repeating string such as `<br>------------------<br>`. What would be a simple JS code (no jQuery if possible) to find the 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc. occurrance of this string on the page or div and then jump to it in such a way it appears on the bottom of the page, not top. I plan to use it in my nav, use addEventListener on nav elements linking to specific sections of the page, to be found by this `<br>------------------<br>` string. Thank you very much.

Comment: So you wish to find the section separator and then scroll to it? Is the html rendered?

Comment: Hi, yes. What you mean by the word "rendered"? I plan to load this long text from an external text file into a <div> in html file.

Comment: Okay... Thanks. Try the code I just posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the JavaScript's `Element.prototype.scrollIntoView` function as shown below:

```js
document.getElementById("holder").innerHTML = document.getElementById("holder").innerHTML.replace(/------------------/g, "<span class='sections-seper'>------------------</span>");

var choice = parseInt(prompt("Which section would you like to go to?", "Number"));
document.getElementsByClassName("sections-seper")[(choice - 1)].scrollIntoView(true);
```

```css
#holder {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id='holder'>
------------------
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sodales dolor velit, in accumsan diam auctor et. Cras malesuada dui sem, non ultrices purus tristique eu. Aenean eu nunc eu lacus tincidunt aliquam. Etiam eget ex libero. Pellentesque et tortor a neque dictum maximus ac eu metus. Nunc laoreet justo in purus lobortis interdum eu sit amet dui. Curabitur et odio in lacus pellentesque porta.
------------------
Suspendisse imperdiet justo vel sapien commodo consequat. Mauris pharetra vulputate bibendum. Vivamus fringilla porta lorem, et tincidunt urna tincidunt nec. Integer lobortis, erat non convallis sagittis, mauris sapien venenatis ligula, eu facilisis est dolor congue odio. Curabitur at diam et sem semper eleifend ac vitae lacus. Vivamus a aliquam nunc, in fringilla risus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Quisque aliquam libero massa, ut pharetra purus ullamcorper ut. Nullam felis leo, finibus sed justo ac, feugiat interdum libero. Cras accumsan bibendum lectus. Cras sollicitudin, augue at fringilla elementum, nulla orci porta massa, ut condimentum lacus massa in elit. Aliquam ut urna ultrices, suscipit metus ac, aliquam mauris.
------------------
Maecenas ac gravida purus. Sed sem nisi, accumsan nec placerat eu, luctus ut nunc. Proin et hendrerit quam. Maecenas sapien orci, pharetra ut diam non, tristique finibus nisl. Curabitur venenatis viverra euismod. Proin vel lacus eu tortor fringilla porttitor eget eget quam. Sed eu rutrum enim. Donec sit amet vestibulum urna, eu cursus eros.
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks, This is not exactly what I wanted though, I would like to avoid using any <hr> or <br> on any other tag, just search for text. Is that possible?

Comment: <hr> would be your section separator here

Comment: Okay, I edited the code so the section separator is `<br>------------------<br>`. Do you want the line breaks to render or not?

Comment: Any solution without using <br> or any other tag? Thanks

Comment: This new edit does not require tags, and instead uses JavaScript and RegEx to search for occurrences of our section separator and inject tags between the text, then scroll to the newly created element.